# ROR: devise-jwt : how to call jwt_revoked? function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-jwt

I am using devise and devise-jwt for my ror api.
I would like to let know the user (by api call) if the user bearer token sent is revoked or not.

I made this route:

```rb
  def user_token_revoked
    decoder = JWT::Decode.new(
      request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1],
      'GENERATED_TOKEN',
      nil,
      nil
    )
    decoded = decoder.decode_segments
    user = User.find_by_id(decoded[0]['sub']) # get id user from decoded token
    render json: user.jwt_revoked?(decoded), status: :ok
  end
```

But it produces me this error:
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `jwt_revoked?' for #User:0x0000558992eb9b98>

I am using this jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtBlacklist in my model:

```rb
class JwtBlacklist < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Denylist
  self.table_name = 'jwt_blacklists'
end
```

How to call jwt_revoked? function ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jwt_revoked?` is part of the `Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Denylist` module. So you'll need to call `JwtBlacklist` model

```
JwtBlacklist.jwt_revoked?(decoded, user)
```